# RoR 'new' command hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just starting ruby on rails. In terminal, I entered "rails new TestApp", and this is what happens at terminal:

```
  create  
  create  README
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install
```

And it hangs there. Should I just exit it and continue with the app? Why doesn't it give me back the control to terminal?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** it asked me for my password and installed some gems. But it does that every time i create a new rails project. is this normal?
Thanks.

Comment: For how long? How's your network/CPU speed?

Comment: I'd really consider using rvm or rbenv, that'll avoid the password thing. But `bundle install` allows a project's gems to be installed relatively easily.  It shouldn't need to re-install gems if they're already installed, unless you *are* using rvm and creating new gemsets.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. How can i make it stop doing that?

Comment: well, that might be the problem, permissions that is.  I am assuming you are on some unix variant.  The installations may not be complete since you didn't have the right permissions to install at the default location via `bundle install`.  I plus one the suggestion for using [rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

Comment: I am using Mac, and i noticed when I installed rails gem, it installed in my home directory.

Comment: You should definitely install RVM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The system is "hanging" because it is installing all the gems, via `bundle install` in the Gemfile that `rails new <project>` generates.  This is the intended behavior.  It asks for your password so that it may install some files that it will need `sudo` access to write (most likely placing the `rail` executable in your path).

You can skip the `bundle install` step when calling `rails new` by passing it the `--skip-bundle` argument.  You will still have to call `bundle install` before you can run your application, but at least you can control *when* it happens.

It is useful to use the `--skip-bundle` when you know that you are going to change the Gemfile, so that you don't have to wait for bundler to install all the gems before running it again within a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly stale question, but for what it's worth this seems to now be fixed. If you update rails (`gem update rails`) it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As most of the comments mentioned its good to have rvm to control your gems. This hangup is most probably because of a permission issue,

You may try to install the gem in the normal way and see if it works

```
gem install <gem name>
```

and following is a basic write up on using rvm with gem sets (which I wrote some time back) (http://keepthingssimple.tumblr.com/post/11274588229/using-rvm-to-keep-things-simple)